# Magento After adding the double quote in attribute option swatch images not change in front-end

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, configurable-swatches

In Magento 1.9.1, I have added a **size attribute** and add a option to that size attribute as `Large 9.5" Tall x 7.5" Diameter & Small 2" Tall x 5.75" Diameter`. After adding this option with **double quote (“) for inch** the images not change after select the large or small option from dropdown. Please let me know how to fix this issue. Because we need double quote for display the inches.

> Error in console :- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token t in JSON
>   at position 28

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it works (not tested just an idea)-

```
Large 9.5\" Tall x 7.5\" Diameter & Small 2\" Tall x 5.75\"
```

Comment: already tried this but not working

Comment: whats the error in console ?

Comment: I have update the console error in question please check

Comment: yes .as expected it is giving error due to quotes

Comment: can you try this one more  `Large 9.5&quot; Tall x 7.5&quot; Diameter & Small 2&quot;  Tall x 5.75&quot; `